# What is the $xy$ equation of a point particle of a rigid body experiencing rolling motion where $v_{cm}=R \omega$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, geometry

What I mean is, say that we know the $xy$ equation for a point particle's projectile motion. i.e., $$y=x \tan(\theta)+\frac{x^2}{u^2} \cos^2(\theta)$$ Is there a similar equation for rolling motion?

Comment: A particle cannot roll since it has no dimensions. Are you talking about a particle as part of a solid body? Please [edit] the question since there are multiple shapes that _can_ roll without sliding, including square wheels on specially shaped roads.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The curve traced by a point belonging to a disc in pure rolling is a [cycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid#:%7E:text=In%20geometry%2C%20a%20cycloid%20is,curve%20rolling%20on%20another%20curve.).
In Cartesian coordinates it reads
$$x=R\cos^{-1}(1-y/R)-\sqrt{y(2R-y)}.$$